# Mininet additional veth pair between host and server

Tags: linux, linux-networking, chroot, openvswitch

For those who don’t know - Mininet is a tool that allows for the automated creation of multiple OVS switches, chroot linux ‘containers’ as hosts and links them all together to prototype OVS powered networks.

I’m trying to create a slightly out of the box mininet environment and stuck with how mininet handles containers and networking. I understand that when you create a new host in mininet, a veth pair is created between the mininet instance and the ‘host’.

[image]

In this diagram, I’ve outlined the standard mininet behaviour in blue - the veth pair between the mininet instance and the host. I’m trying to create link inscribed in red, a veth pair between the mininet ‘host’ and the linux networking stack on the mininet server.

This scenario would allow me to run a controller on the host and communicate with the host mininet machine and the rest of the virtual network.

How would I go about creating a new veth pair between a chroot ‘container’ and the host machine?

Comment: The distro you use is important for me to answer this question.

Comment: This is running on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

You can a new veth pair with the following commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTAINERPID=$(get the pid of the container)
ip link add dev swport1 type veth peer h1-eth1
ip link set dev swport1 up
ip link set netns "${CONTAINERPID}" dev h1-eth1
```

This will created a 'downed' link in the container, which you will need to bring up inside of the container and add IP addresses etc to.